# How to show the total number of pages in the pagination bar

Tags: ce-1.8.1.0, pagination

I need to change the display of pagination in the category page.

Current format is :
1 2 3 4 5 next page

and i need to be

1 2 3 4 5 ... 20 next page

where 20 is the number of total pages.

Do you know how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

goto `app/design/frontend/your_namespace/your_theme/template/page/html/pager.html`

Find

```
<?php if ($this->canShowLast()): ?>
     <li><a class="last" href="<?php echo $this->getLastPageUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->getLastPageNum() ?></a></li>
<?php endif;?>
```

In this hide the condition. i.e,

```
<li><a class="last" href="<?php echo $this->getLastPageUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->getLastPageNum() ?></a></li>
```

Just try this. I think you can get the result.

Comment: Thanks for reply but unfortunately nothing changed